# Why os.sytem won't show desktop notification to user?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

I have a simple Python script here:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import os

os.system('notify-send Hello "This is a message"')
```

When I, as a normal user, run the script in terminal as `./notification.py`, a desktop notification is displayed on the screen with the contents *Hello This is a message*. However, when I (normal user) run `sudo ./notification.py`, no desktop notification is shown. I am unable to understand this behaviour and how to go about solving it or working around it.

PS:
OS - OpenSUSE Leap 42.1 
DE - KDE Plasma v5.5.5

Comment: Can you try using the `subprocess` module so you can capture the return code and potential stderr from your command?

Comment: In both instances the return code is 0

Comment: I don't know then. I don't have a Linux box with Plasma. Wish I could help!